# Comparison of Integer with nil failed (ArgumentError) while solving Insertion Sort with Ruby

Tags: ruby, insertion-sort, argument-error

Below is the updated code:

```
def insertion_sort(list)
  num = list.length
  for i in (0..(num-2))
    if list[i] > list[i+1] && i == 0
      list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
      i+=1
    elsif list[i] == list[i+1]
      i+=1
    elsif list[i] > list[i+1] && i > 0
      len = (list[0..(i+1)].length)
      list2 = list[0..(i+1)]
      list = list - list2
      count = 0
      while count <= len+1
        if list2[len-1] < list2[len-2]
           list2[len-2],list2[len-1]= list2[len-1],list2[len-2] 
        elsif  list2[len-1] == list2[len-2]
          count+=1
          len-=len
        else
         count+=1
         len-=1 
        end
      end
       list = list2 + list  
    end
  end
   list
end

p insertion_sort([2,1,4,8,7,3,100,99,8])
p insertion_sort([2,1,4,8,8,7,3,100,99])
p insertion_sort([3790,780,780,1,55])
```

**Summary:**

1. code works if two identical integers are right next to each other :[2,1,4,8,8,7,3,100,99] and the array size > 5.
2. if the two identical integer are at random positions: [2,1,4,8,7,3,100,99,8]. Below error would occur
   aaa.rb:4:in `>': comparison of Integer with nil failed (ArgumentError)

with Line 4 code being: if list[i] > list[i+1] && i == 0

To solve 1. I changed the while loop to "while count <= len+1",
so when array size is smaller than 5 the code would work. But not when identical integers are at random positions.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code works fine for me (output is [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 8, 99, 100]). What version of Ruby are you running it again?

Comment: @CormacMulhall currently using Ruby 3.0.0p0. Which version did you test the code on? thanks!

Comment: Tested with 3.0.2 and 2.7.4 (the latest releases on 3 and 2 branch). The error is implying that `i` is going out of bounds of the list, which I can't see why that would happen based on your code. You sure the code you are running isn't slightly different to the code you pasted here?

Comment: @CormacMulhall Actually the array above [2,1,4,8,8,7,3,100,99] worked without errors. But I tested another more extreme array [3790,1,780,55,23,50,1111,60,50], and I ended up getting the ArgumentError. "comparison of Integer with nil failed". Can't figure out why it's going out of bounds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification in the comments. I see the problem now.

In the swap algorithm here

```rb
elsif list[i] > list[i+1] && i > 0
  len = (list[0..(i+1)].length)
  list2 = list[0..(i+1)]
  list = list - list2
  count = 0
  while count <= len+1
    ...
```

you are trying to split the array in two. You get `list2` which is the first half of the array and then try and get the second half by ***subtracting*** `list2` from `list`.

The problem with using **subtract** here is that if you have duplicates it will remove them and make your lists too short.

In the example `[3790,1,780,55,23,50,1111,60,50]` you should have a `50` in the first array and a `50` in the second half.

But using subtract removes one of those `50`.

When you add the two temporary lists back together you are now one element short (the missing `50`) and you get an out of bounds error when you get to the end of the array and try and access this 9th element which no longer exists.

Instead of using subtract here simply use the same method you used to make `list2`.

```rb
list2 = list[0..(i+1)] # All elements in list from position 0 to i+1
list = list[(i+2)..-1] # All elements in list from position i+2 to end of list
```

Now `list` and `list2` are just the original list split, and when you add them back together are the end they should be the same length

```rb
def insertion_sort(list)
  num = list.length
  for i in (0..(num-2))
    if list[i] > list[i+1] && i == 0
      list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
      i+=1
    elsif list[i] == list[i+1]
      i+=1
    elsif list[i] > list[i+1] && i > 0
      len = (list[0..(i+1)].length)
      list2 = list[0..(i+1)]
      list = list[(i+2)..-1]
      count = 0
      while count <= len+1
        if list2[len-1] < list2[len-2]
           list2[len-2],list2[len-1]= list2[len-1],list2[len-2] 
        elsif  list2[len-1] == list2[len-2]
          count+=1
          len-=len
        else
         count+=1
         len-=1 
        end
      end
       list = list2 + list  
    end
  end
   list
end

p insertion_sort([2,1,4,8,7,3,100,99,8])
p insertion_sort([2,1,4,8,8,7,3,100,99])
p insertion_sort([3790,780,780,1,55])
```

Comment: Thanks Cormac! I was just about to test list subtracting and adding, but luckily I read your answer first. Very thorough 100!